# Best way to do Async server communications from multiple Activities

Tags: android, asynchronous, communication

I'm having problems trying to find the best way to do two-way server communications, asynchronously. I am able to do the server communications hard coded to a server (no encapsulation, async calls), but I want to know what the best way to do it is. There's a protocol for logging in, registering, changing location, etc.
The server communications are using JSON and HTTPPost. The app would be sending JSON data and receiving it and putting it into a database.

I thought of making a ServerCommuncations class which holds data such as username, password, etc. and instantiates the HTTPRequest objects and other common objects. This could be inside a Bound service.

Now I could use a Bound Service with an AsyncTask, however multiple Activities in the app will need to do server communications so it would mean binding the service to multiple Activities.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is there a better way?
3. If I was to use the bound service, would it be best to use Messengers or extend Binder class?

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for handling asynchronous code.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the chosen method. It works like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a real Thread and pass it a handler which is a singleton. you could then use the handler in all your activites.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Could do, but I would be wanting do a log in or an update location call. This feels messy to do. How would you differentiate which task you want to achieve?

Comment: eighter do a seperate thread for each task, or create an abstract class with derivatives for each task to be passed to the thread